# Django mysql error in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, django-models, mysql-python

I have started to learn django and python and also I am new in using ubuntu. for my first program I need mysql so I already have installed it and when I use mysql command I have this result.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 40
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

but when I run this command according to django site instruction

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I have this error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

moreover I have done some modification in settings.py file like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'firstprojectdb',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

why this is happend? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what the problem is: you haven't installed the MySQLdb library, which Django needs to talk to the database.

You can install it with `pip install mysql-python` or `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`.

Comment: There are a few system dependencies. Probably better to use the second option I gave, since apt-get will install the dependencies for you.

Comment: I did it but still I have previous error after run `python manage.py syncdb` command. should I do anything in manage.py?